# How to call model methods with model created dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have some models need to be initialized dynamically.

```
model = <INPUT_STRING>.capitalize.constantize.new
```

But I can not call `where` method by `model.where(~)`

It will show

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<User:0x007fb1142a0978>
```

Comment: You're trying to call `where` on `User` instance instead of class. BTW, do you sanitize your input somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Do not create new object

```
model = <INPUT_STRING>.capitalize.constantize
```

thats all you need

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `model` is an instance of the `User` class. Remove the `new` method at the end of your line of code to get it to work.